# "The specified key does not exist" while creating CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have created an s3 bucket and uploaded an image in it. My s3 url is working and fine but when I try this with cloudfront url it shows me this error.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>s3://avanish2302/justice.jpg/</Key>
<RequestId>B8BF8D5981519FF9</RequestId>
<HostId>RQ2CwxcujOp648JZD9dg6HD/4DVOtEs7/sJ86qWvR0oVfQn7FtAzH0+XN7mwwtwEdOriOJQ/V6w=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have tried copying the object path from the s3 and pasted in the object path while creating cloudfront.

Its strange that when I tried it before using the same steps, it used to work fine but now when I follow the same steps, it shows me this error.

My s3 bucket and object are set to public. Does anyone have this problem?

Comment: Have you set as website hosting? for S3 if you want to open as public you have use as website hosting with cloudfront.

Comment: *"I have tried copying the object path from the s3 and pasted in the object path while creating cloudfront."*  You pasted it where, in which setting?  **Origin Path** in CloudFront is an advanced configutation setting that is almost always left empty, and setting that value would potentially be one way to get this error.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

They key should not have s3:// in front of it. You configured that as your origin already.  The key is location of the file in the bucket (justice.jpg, no trailing slash).  Also, see this https://www.fernandomc.com/posts/amazon-s3-static-sites-and-cloudfront-configuration/